# Moving to recycle bin from elevated process

Tags: delphi, winapi, uac, recycle-bin

I am using SHFileOperationW function with FO_DELETE parameter to move a file to recycle bin (if recycle bin is not disabled).

The problem is when I log as **non-admin** user and run my application as admin. The files are moved to **admin's** recycle bin.

Is it possible to make it so the files are moved to the currenly logged non-admin user's recycle bin?

My idea was to run separate non-elevated process and move it to recycle bin from there. But I am not sure if a better solution exists. I tried to find answer on internet, but did not succeed.

Comment: Seems the proper thing would not to launch your application as administrator in the first place. If you have a task that requires administrative privilege, spawn a separate process that requests elevation.

Comment: thank you, I have solved it as you say.

Answer (score 0):

I would propose the following routine - tested on Delphi XE 10.

```
function File2Trash(const FileName: string): boolean;
var
    fos: TSHFileOpStruct;
begin
      FillChar(fos, SizeOf(fos), 0);
      with fos do
      begin
        wFunc  := FO_DELETE;
        pFrom  := PChar(ExpandFileName(FileName)+#0#0);
        fFlags := FOF_ALLOWUNDO or FOF_NOCONFIRMATION or FOF_SILENT or FOF_NOERRORUI;
      end;
      Result := (0 = ShFileOperation(fos));
end;
```

Some details are important:

- no relative path should be used, existing path should be expanded to
  full one;
- adding #0#0 to the end of file name is the must;
- to keep this operation silent I would propose to use one more flag
  FOF_NOERRORUI.

Answer (score -1):

When I needed to use this routine, I used the following commands.
I hope it is useful.

> > Tests with Delphi 2010 and Windows 8.

```
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  vMsg : string;
begin
  // If want permanently delete
  //deletefile(edit1.text);

  SendFileToTrash(edit1.Text, vMsg);

  if (vMsg = '') then
  begin
    ShowMessage('File sent to the trash.');
  end else begin
    ShowMessage(vMsg);
  end;

end;


procedure TForm2.SendFileToTrash(const aFileName: TFileName; var MsgError: string);
var
  Op: TSHFileOpStruct;
begin
  {Very importante
     Include in Uses  SysUtils and ShellAPI;
  }
  MsgError := '';

  if not (FileExists(aFileName)) then
  begin
    MsgError := 'File not found.';
    Exit;
  end;

  FillChar(Op, SizeOf(Op), 0);

  Op.wFunc := FO_DELETE;
  Op.pFrom := PChar(aFileName+#0);
  Op.fFlags := FOF_ALLOWUNDO or FOF_NOCONFIRMATION or FOF_SILENT;

  if (ShFileOperation(Op) <> 0) then
  begin
      MsgError := 'Could not send the file to the trash.';
  end;

end;
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunatelly this does not answer my question. I use almost same code.

Comment: see detail of this line [Op.pFrom := PChar(aFileName+#0);], but specifically the +#0. Without this code snippet does not work.

Comment: I think that you did not understand the question. Please read my question again. Thanks.